# I have a vba macro, that copy down the last cells value and highlights the bold text with red color

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro code, that copy down the last cells value and highlights the bold text with red color.

There is one problem occurring in last cell, although it copy down the last cell value of grouped cells, but it could not highlights the bold text with red color.

Check the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQJk.jpg
[image]

Here is the VBA code:

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    For Each rr In r
        with rr
            .FillDown
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        end with
    Next

    Cells(N + 1, "A").FillDown
End Sub
```

Please check the code, and suggest me what should i do?

Comment: How does that `.filldown` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming from the code you have provided that the before picture has blanks, then you want to fill in the blanks with the cell above and color it red and **bold**. Including below the last cell.

### Here is the Picture I am getting with the code you provided.

[image]

### This is my interpretation on how to do that.

```
Sub Blank_It()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N, "A"))

    For Each rr In r.Cells

        If IsEmpty(rr) Then

            With rr
                .Value = .Offset(-1).Value
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With

        End If

    Next rr

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you assume correct. Exactly I want the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what I think you are attempting using your original code (including `.FillDown`), add one to `N` in your `Set r` statement. The last `.filldown` is then not needed.

```
Sub copy_down()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(N + 1, "A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    For Each rr In r
        with rr
            .FillDown
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        end with
    Next

End Sub
```